# Getting an error while creating new instance of SchemaFactory

Tags: java, android, xml, xsd

I am getting an exception while doing:

```
factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

i am getting ileagal parameters,
someone maybe know why?

**Partial Stack Trace**

> android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117),
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935),
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99),
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123),
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691),
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method),
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507),
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847),
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605),
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)]

Comment: You may know better than us as u know what u r doing or related codes. :d

Comment: Your question is valid, but to improve it's quality please read the [stackoverflow question checklist](http://tinyurl.com/so-list).

Comment: @AndroidKiller it won't hurt the stackoverflow databases, if you spell out the words you are using ;)

Comment: @jlordo Nice to meet you Mr English teacher.

Comment: @AndroidKiller sorry if you feel offended by my comment, that was not my intention. I still stand by my point, for most people it's easier to read _you are_ instead of _u r_. The latter only makes sense where there is a tight character count restriction.

Comment: @jlordo come on this is a comment so i dont mind to use 'u' instead of 'you'

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to properly escape the colon, per
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newInstance(java.lang.String)

Try `factory =  SchemaFactory.newInstance("http\://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");`

Comment: You are basically right, but your code has an eror: You have an invalid escape sequence. It won't compile. I think you mean `...("http:\\://www...`

Comment: anyone can help me? i am getting "IllegalArgumentException" exception, which is according to oracle means no implementation of the schema language is available. what does it means?
Thanks